# I am doing a coin toss game program. But i am having an error in this portion [ (if Guess==i) {. How do I solve this?

Tags: java, if-statement, coin-flipping, java-package

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinTossGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {


   System.out.println("A coin is tossed!");

      int Heads=0, Tails=1;

   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter your guess.");   //Starting message
   System.out.println("Press 0 for Heads and 1 for Tails.");   //prompts user to enter the input

        String Guess = input.nextLine( );   //Stored input in variable
        int i= (int) (Math.random () * 2);   //Store random number

        if (Guess==i) {
        System.out.println("Nice guess.\nYou are really guenius!!"); 
    }
        else {
        System.out.println("Opps! wrong guess.");
        System.out.println("Try again.");
        System.out.println("Thank you.");
   }

}
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because "i am having an error" is not a useful problem statement.  Please [edit] your question to include the error that you are getting, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: You are comparing an INT with a STRING ...

Comment: /CoinTossGame.java:19: error: incomparable types: String and int
            if (Guess==i) {
                     ^
1 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare an Integer with a String. That obviously can not work. Convert either `Guess` into `int` or `i` into `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an `int` with a `String` : `if (Guess==i)`

What you need is 2 ints :

```
int guess = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());    //or  int guess = input.nextInt();
int i = (int) (Math.random () * 2);                //Store random number

if (guess==i) {
    System.out.println("Nice guess.\nYou are really guenius!!"); 
}
```

---

Or with 2 `Strings` :

```
String guess = input.nextLine();    
String i = ((int) (Math.random () * 2)) + "";

if (guess.equals(i)) {                      // for object use equals() and not ==
    System.out.println("Nice guess.\nYou are really guenius!!"); 
}
```